# OpenTBS - pb merging xlsx

Tags: xlsx, opentbs

I'd like to merge a xlsx file with data from a MySQL dB. I am not very comfortable with programming in general but I have already wrote some codes in PHP using TBS.
Anyway, I decided to start from the demo file (demo_ms_excel.php) that is corretly running on my server. Thant I just modified this file to put an include with all the data required for the dB connexion and when I re-test the demo file, Excel refuses to open the generated file (Impossible to open "demo_ms_excel_2020-04-10-9.xlsx" because its format or extension is not valid ...(translated from french)). Do you have any clue ? Can it be a format problem from my code editor (PSPad)) ?
Thanks for helping...

Comment: Bonjour Etienne, it‘s too difficult to reply without more clue, or more code. Maybe they are some PHP error ouput in your result XLSX.

Comment: Salut Skrol, I send U that ! Thank you !